# Delphi Change resolution of webcam in directshow

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, directshow

i am trying to change the resolution of the frames to 320x240 because my webcam is providing frames in 640x480 and the encoder i am using is not working right with higher resolution, i do it this way

```pascal
procedure OnDevieStart()
begin
  FilterGraph.ClearGraph;
  FilterGraph.Active := False;
  Filter.BaseFilter.Moniker := SysDev.GetMoniker(TMenuItem(Sender).tag);
  FilterGraph.Active := true;
  SetVideoProperties(Filter as iBaseFilter);

  with FilterGraph as ICaptureGraphBuilder2 do
  try
    RenderStream(@PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, nil, Filter as IBaseFilter, SampleGrabber as IBaseFilter, VideoWindow as IbaseFilter);
    FilterGraph.Play;
  except
    ShowMessage('Unable to use specified device!')
  end;
end;

function SetVideoProperties(pVideoCapture: IBaseFilter):Boolean;
var
  hr:HRESULT;
  pStreamConfig: IAMStreamConfig;
  pAM_Media: PAMMediaType;
  pvih: PVIDEOINFOHEADER;
  pICGP2: ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
begin

  pICGP2 := FilterGraph as ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
  hr := pICGP2.FindInterface(@PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, nil, pVideoCapture,
                             IID_IAMStreamConfig, pStreamConfig);

  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) then begin

    pStreamConfig.GetFormat(pAM_Media);
    pvih := pAM_Media.pbFormat ;
    pAM_Media.subtype := MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biWidth := 320;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biHeight := 240;
    pvih.AvgTimePerFrame := 10000000 div 15;
    pStreamConfig.SetFormat(pAM_Media^);
    DeleteMediaType(pAM_Media);
    pStreamConfig := nil;
  end;

end;
```

But the resolution stays the same when grabbing the frames through the sample grabber

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

**UPDATE**

Ok i think i am now updating all the members

```pascal
function SetVideoProperties(pVideoCapture: IBaseFilter):Boolean;
var
  hr:HRESULT;
  pStreamConfig: IAMStreamConfig;
  pAM_Media: PAMMediaType;
  pvih: PVIDEOINFOHEADER;
  pICGP2: ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
begin

  pICGP2 := FilterGraph as ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
  hr := pICGP2.FindInterface(@PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, nil, pVideoCapture,
                             IID_IAMStreamConfig, pStreamConfig);

  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) then begin

    pStreamConfig.GetFormat(pAM_Media);

    pAM_Media.subtype := MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24;
    pAM_Media.majortype := MEDIATYPE_Video;
    pAM_Media.bFixedSizeSamples := True;
    pAM_Media.bTemporalCompression := False;
    pAM_Media.lSampleSize := 230400;
    pAM_Media.formattype := FORMAT_VideoInfo;
    pAM_Media.pUnk := nil;
    pAM_Media.cbFormat := 88;

    pvih := pAM_Media.pbFormat;
    pvih.dwBitRate := 6912000;
    pvih.AvgTimePerFrame := 10000000 div 15;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biSize := 40;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biWidth := 320;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biHeight := 240;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biPlanes := 1;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biBitCount := 24;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biCompression := 0;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biSizeImage := 230400;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter := 0;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter := 0;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biClrUsed := 0;
    pvih.bmiHeader.biClrImportant := 0;

    hr := pStreamConfig.SetFormat(pAM_Media^);

    If Succeeded(hr) then ShowMessage('SUCCEED') else ShowMessage(IntToStr(hr));   
    DeleteMediaType(pAM_Media);
    pStreamConfig := nil;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: i am now updating all the members but it is still giving the same error, i updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

1. Your initialization of new media type with new resolution is incorrect/incomplete: update other members as well
2. You should be checking `SetFormat` result to detect failures in format settings
3. The code itself appears to be incomplete, there is no evidence you are at all changing the format and the source filter exists and added to the filter graph

Comment: can you please explain with a code?? if thats not asking too much. thanks

Comment: Which is 0x80004005 `E_FAIL` - as I said it rejected your format change attempt.

Comment: Hmmm.. so what should i do here? what other members are must to be updated?

Comment: All members. You should have a well-formed media type.

Comment: i am now updating all the members but it is still giving the same error, i updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

See DSPack demo "...\dspack2.3.4\Demos\D6-D7\videocap"

You need to enumerate all availible formats of webcam, and then set one.

Thats the code from there: 
(button Start OnClick handler)

```
VideoMediaTypes, 
AudioMediaTypes: TEnumMediaType;

....... 

      // configure output Video media type
      if VideoSourceFilter.FilterGraph <> nil then
      begin
        PinList := TPinList.Create(VideoSourceFilter as IBaseFilter);
        if VideoFormats.ItemIndex <> -1 then
          with (PinList.First as IAMStreamConfig) do
            SetFormat(VideoMediaTypes.Items[VideoFormats.ItemIndex].AMMediaType^);
        PinList.Free;
      end;
```

Here

```
  SetFormat(VideoMediaTypes.Items[VideoFormats.ItemIndex].AMMediaType^);
```

`VideoMediaTypes` is a list of available formats that populated when user selects the Source.

`VideoFormat` is GUI control (ListBox) for selecting the format